# how to loop inside promise async await method?

Tags: javascript

i wanna make output like this :

kembalian 1: 30000
kembalian 2: 20000
kembalian 3: 10000
kembalian 4: 5000

so after kembalian, there is number, but i wanna make it automaticly

with this code

```js
function beliPromise(uang, harga) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        setTimeout(function () {

            const kembalian = uang - harga;

            let angka = i

            for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                console.log(i)

            }

            console.log(`kembalian ${angka}: ${kembalian}`);

            if (kembalian > 0) {
                resolve(kembalian);
            } else {
                reject(0); // atau bisa reject('uang anda habis bro :(')
            }
        }, 500)
    })
}

async function kembalianAwait() {
    try {
        const kembalian1 = await beliPromise(50000, 20000);
        const kembalian2 = await beliPromise(kembalian1, 10000);
        const kembalian3 = await beliPromise(kembalian2, 10000);
        const kembalian4 = await beliPromise(kembalian3, 5000);
        // const kembalian5 = await beliPromise(kembalian4, 50000);
        // return kembalian5;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}


kembalianAwait()
```

how could be ?

Comment: Don't use a loop. Make the index a global variable, and increment it in the function.

Comment: Not sure, What's your requirement was why to use promises/asyc awaits for this.

Comment: @barmar could you explain, how make index global variable ?

Comment: @surya no requirement at all, i studied async await last time, and i curious, how if i modified, there is a number information after "kembalian". so it will looks more nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "await" in a for loop, for example:

```
function beliPromise(uang, harga) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            const kembalian = uang - harga;
            if (kembalian >= 0) {
                resolve(kembalian);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        }, 500)
    })
}

let uang = 50000;
async function kembalianAwait() {
    const harga = [20000, 10000, 10000, 5000];
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < harga.length; i++) {
            let kembalian = await beliPromise(uang, harga[i])
            console.log(`kembalian ${i + 1}: ${kembalian}`);
            uang = kembalian
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

And note the usage of `>=0`, I think having the exact amount of money should not result in an Error.

Comment: wow thanks bro, its cool code, i learnd many things from this code

Answer (score 1):

Use a global index variable:

```js
var index  = 1

function beliPromise(uang, harga) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const kembalian = uang - harga;

    console.log(`kembalian ${index}: ${kembalian}`);

    index ++;

    if (kembalian > 0) {
      resolve(kembalian);
    } else {
      reject(0); // atau bisa reject('uang anda habis bro :(')
    }
    
  })
}

async function kembalianAwait() {
  try {
    const kembalian1 = await beliPromise(50000, 20000);
    const kembalian2 = await beliPromise(kembalian1, 10000);
    const kembalian3 = await beliPromise(kembalian2, 10000);
    const kembalian4 = await beliPromise(kembalian3, 5000);
    // const kembalian5 = await beliPromise(kembalian4, 50000);
    // return kembalian5;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}

kembalianAwait()
```

Comment: nah thanks sir @ask4you, this is what i want, with add simple code, i got what i want, thanks, i still learn programming, so i dont know a simple thing like this

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop, but reference i outside the loop. You need to include the loop's code into the loop:

```js
function beliPromise(uang, harga) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        setTimeout(function () {

            const kembalian = uang - harga;

            for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                let angka = i

                console.log(i)
                console.log(`kembalian ${angka}: ${kembalian}`);

                if (kembalian > 0) {
                    resolve(kembalian);
                } else {
                    reject(0); // atau bisa reject('uang anda habis bro :(')
                }

            }

        }, 500)
    })
}

async function kembalianAwait() {
    try {
        const kembalian1 = await beliPromise(50000, 20000);
        const kembalian2 = await beliPromise(kembalian1, 10000);
        const kembalian3 = await beliPromise(kembalian2, 10000);
        const kembalian4 = await beliPromise(kembalian3, 5000);
        // const kembalian5 = await beliPromise(kembalian4, 50000);
        // return kembalian5;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}


kembalianAwait()
```

Comment: its not what i want, because the output of every "kembalian" looping 10 times